# send multiple jms messages in one transaction

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have to send a message to 2 different queues(queue1 and queue2). However, i want to rollback,  if the send is failed for any of the queue(queue1 or queue2).

my source code looks as follows. can anyone through some inputs on this.

```
  public void sendMessage(final Map<String, String> mapMessage) {

    jmsTemplate.send(queue1, session -> {
      MapMessage message = session.createMapMessage();
      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = mapMessage.entrySet().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
        message.setStringProperty(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
      }
      message.setJMSRedelivered(true);
      message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", ""));
      return message;
    });

    jmsTemplate.send(queue2, session -> {
      MapMessage message = session.createMapMessage();
      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = mapMessage.entrySet().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
        message.setStringProperty(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
      }
      message.setJMSRedelivered(true);
      message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", ""));
      return message;
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a transaction before entering the `sendMessage` method, e.g. with `@Transactional` - see the [Spring Framework Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: Hi Gary, i tried both javax and spring based @Transactional seperately. But, it didn't worked. I changed the code as below. It worked. However, i am wondering, how can we do this Declarative instead of programmatic rollback.   Resource
  PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager;
  TransactionStatus status = jmsTransactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition()); After the second jmsTemplate.send, i use commit. In exception block, i used rollback.
      jmsTransactionManager.commit(status);
or       jmsTransactionManager.rollback(status);

Comment: You must have misconfigured something. Declarative transactions should work fine. Don't try to put code in comments here; virtually unreadable.  Edit the question instead. Read the reference manual carefully. If you still can't figure it out, show all of your config.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue by adding @Transactional of spring. The missing part was EnableTransactionManagement on the spring boot application class. Thanks Gary